# Key Error - An error in the python bot code

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

Good evening, I am developing a bot that will search for a telegram account by phone number. Tell me what I'm doing wrong: KeyError 'result' crashes.
user = response['result']

```
# Импортируем модули
import telebot
import requests

# Указываем токен 
bot = telebot.TeleBot('')

# Обработчик команды Start
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите номер телефона для поиска аккаунта телеграмм')

# Обработчик ввода номера телефона
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_text(message):
    # Запрос для поиска пользователя
    url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot{bot}/getUserByPhone' + 'phone_number=' + message.text
    response = requests.get(url).json()
    
    # Проверка существования пользователя
    if 'message' in response:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Аккаунт телеграмм не найден')
    else:
        user = response['result'] 
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Указанный аккаунт был найден:\n\n' +
                         'ID пользователя: ' + str(user['id']) + '\n\n' +
                         'Имя пользователя: ' + user['first_name'])

# Запуск бота
bot.polling()
```

I tried to deal with the error myself, but since I'm not strong in python, it didn't work out for me

Comment: check the response. the error is pretty clear, there is no key 'result'

Comment: Yes, I understand this, but I'm still green and can't take action to fix and properly function the script, could you help me?

Comment: You could change the `else:` to `elif 'result' in response:` and then have a final `else:` to handle the case that neither `'message'` nor `'result'` is in `response`.

Comment: Thanks, John Coleman